# Approver name is not populating in Classic email template while requesting for Approval

Tags: email-template, approval-process, custom

I'm creating Custom Email Template(Text) for Approval aprocess in order to get email notifications. But instead of populating approver name in first line after Hi "ApproverName" it's priniting the requester name who is submitting the approval request. Below is the email template,

```
Hi {!ApprovalRequest.Process_Approver},

{!Approval_Requesting_User.Name} has requested your approval to create this project in Mavenlink : {!Opportunity.Name}.

Please approve that the Opportunity naming convention is correct (Account Abbreviation - Opportunity Name - Sitecore or SF), Contacts are added to the Opportunity and the estimate and outline have been added.

Please visit the link below and either approve or reject it.
{!Opportunity.Link}

Thanks,
```

Please let me know what wrong I'm doing here?

BR,
Abhishek

Comment: Hey @rahul I can't see anything in your comment, you posted a blank!

Comment: I didn't comment, I just edited the post :),

Comment: Okay @rahul, like the post can be edited or available to edit publicly?

Comment: Not everyone can edit the posts, but a person with edit privilege can edit and everyone who has an account can suggest the edit which can be reviewed and approved by the person who has those privileges. Know more about privileges [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)